# Django: How to add multiple class-based forms in a single view?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

In my models.py I have a parent class with one child and one grandchild class. The parent has a one-to-many relationship with the child and the child has a one-to-many relationship with the grandchild.

I would like to create a view (preferably a class-based view as these seem easiest to implement) which includes 3 class-based forms, one for the parent,  multiple for the child and multiple for grandchild.

What I would like to get is a view in which I can submit a form that will create one parent with multiple children with multiple grandchildren.

How would I go best about designing such a view?

models.py:

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    parent_propery_one = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    parent_propery_two = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    parent_propery_three = models.TextField()
    parent_property_four = models.URLField(max_length=300, null=True)
    parent_property_five = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    parent_property_six = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    parent_property_seven = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT)

...

class Child(models.Model):
    child_propery_one = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    child_property_two = models.ForeignKey(Vilt, default=1, verbose_name="Bierviltje", on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    child_property_three = models.BooleanField()

...

class Grandchild(models.Model):
    grandchild_property_one = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    grandchild_property_two = models.ForeignKey(Pand, default=1, verbose_name="Pand", on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    grandchild_property_three = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=2)
    grandchild_property_four = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    grandchild_property_five = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
    grandchild_property_six = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    grandchild_property_seven = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    grandchild_property_eight = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
```

views.py

```
class ParentCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Parent
    template_name = 'parent/parent_form.html'
    fields = ['parent_property_one', 'parent_property_two', 'parent_property_three', 'parent_property_four', 'parent_property_five', 'parent_property_six']
    context_object_name = 'parents'
```

With this code it obviously only returns the form for the parent class. I would like to add the children and grandchildren class-based forms in this view as well. What is the best approach to do this?

Comment: The `CreateView` is meant to create one model. Whilst it is possible to modify it to process multiple forms, I would advise against it, it will get messy. Sometimes a basic view is simpler. I'd use a function view or a `TemplateView` if I were you. And use modelformsets for the children and grandchildren.

Comment: Thanks @dirkgroten! I will try to create it without using the CreateView then.